# Counting the number of names after a certain name from a file?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a program that will count the number of names after the word "Patti" from a file.

```
Private Sub btnP_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnP.Click
    Dim inFile As StreamReader = New StreamReader("pattiparty.txt")
    'Declare the varibles
    Dim variableName As String ' the current names from the file
    Dim names As String
    Do
        'read in the names
        variableName = inFile.ReadLine()
        'determine the two consecutive names after Patti
        If variableName = "Patti" Then
            names = variableName + 2
        End If
    Loop Until variableName = "Patti"
    'the loop keeps going until "Patti" is read

    'output the results
    Me.lblOutput.Text = names

End Sub
```

End Class

Instead of the program is supposed to display the two names after the name "Patti", but I get an error instead.

Comment: You haven't provided a sample of the input file that's supposed to re-produce this behavior.

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On` at the project level...

Comment: Provide a sample of the input file and another one shows how the results should be.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll want to continue looping until both a) the target string "Patti" was read and b) the next 2 lines have been read or end of file was reached. After recognizing the name "Patti", you can set a flag `foundName = true` and for each next line, increment the number of extra names read until both are read or end of line is reached.

Answer (score 0):

With **`variableName = inFile.ReadLine()`**, you're reading a string value, thus with: **`names = variableName + 2`**, you're trying to add the `Integer` value `2` to a String value. No really useful.

You need to read each line of a file and start adding string values to a variable/collection when a specific patter is found. Then decide how many other lines to read from the file.
So, this: **`Loop Until variableName = "Patti"`** won't help, you'ld exit the loop as soon as the patter is found and you'll never get the lines that follow.

Of course, you may have reached the end of the file stream in the meanwhile. Or, possibly, the patter you specified was not found.

A simple solution is to use a boolean flags that is set to `True` as soon the pattern is found, then collect the number of lines specified, if any, only when the flag is set to `True`. Exit the loop when you have harvested what was asked.
The **`While Not (reader.EndOfStream)`** condition ensures that we don't read past the end of the stream.

The last thing to do is to add the strings found to the Text property of the control responsible for presenting the results. Here, I'm using [String.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join) to glue together the resulting strings, separated by a space.

```
Private Sub btnP_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnP.Click
    Dim pattiResults = FileGetLines("pattiparty.txt", "Patti", 2)
    Me.lblOutput.Text = String.Join(" ", pattiResults)
End Sub

Friend Function FileGetLines(filePath As String, searchPatter As String, linesCount As Integer) As List(Of String)
    Dim patternFound As Boolean = False
    Dim result As New List(Of String)

    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(filePath)
        While Not (reader.EndOfStream)
            If reader.ReadLine().Contains(searchPatter) Then patternFound = True
            If patternFound Then
                result.Add(reader.ReadLine())
                If result.Count = linesCount Then
                    Exit While
                End If
            End If
        End While
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```